# Adding "weekly" seasonality in arima R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality

I've found the internet fairly unhelpful with this issue and thought I'd turn. I have the following arima model:

```r
y = data$produced_diff
regs = data[,c(10,11,12)]
    
ar1ma1x = arima(y, xreg=regs, order=c(1,0,1))
```

Pretty simple. The data is daily and I'm trying to add a weekly seasonality. I'm currently doing it like this:

```r
ar1ma1xS = arima(y, xreg=regs, order=c(1, 0, 1),
            seasonal = c(0, 0, 7))
```

I ... think this is right? It runs and gives slightly different output. But I find the documentation fairly opaque.

Comment: See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/

Comment: That post is about weekly data, whereas the question is about daily data with weekly seasonality. See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to use the `Arima()` or `auto.arima()` functions from the `forecast` package, than using the `arima()` function from the `stats` package.

Either way, your time series `y` should be a `ts` object with frequency set to 7.

Setting `seasonal = c(0,0,7)` is unlikely to give a good model. Usually, the seasonal orders would be no more than 2.

If you used the `auto.arima()` function, the orders will be selected automatically:

```
fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg=regs)
```

Documentation for `auto.arima()` is here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html